# How to play manifest file/build url for Azure Media Services v3?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Using v3 of Azure Media Services. My streaming endpoint is running. I want users to upload any type of video file(.avi for example) through the browser and play them without a plugin. I understand that requires background encoding.

I've uploaded an asset, created an encoding job for it and set up a webhook to notify me when its done. I then create a streaming locator for it and store the smooth streaming path.

It ends up looking like:
https://{StreamingEndpoint}/{StreamingLocator}/{filename}.ism/manifest

I can download the manifest file so the url seems correct but I've tried the video in https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html?url=%2F%2F and my own site without success.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, It was a combination of me not understanding the manifest file/my video having no audio that caused the problem.

For the manifest, I was using the smooth streaming link instead of the dash link when playing in Chrome. I've swapped to Azure Media Player from video.js for auto swapping DASH/HLS/SmoothStreaming because I didn't want to handle that myself.

I also came up against the video not playing without audio which I fixed by switching encoding.

Thanks to @johndeu for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of quick questions for clarification.

1. Which encoding setting/preset did you use to encode the AVI file?
2. Does your AVI contain audio or video only? Azure Media Player requires an audio track. You can modify the encoding preset to insert silence if needed.
3. You mentioned that the manifest file downloads and you are able to view it. Have you attempted to stream another protocol. Try DASH (in Edge or Chrome video tag) or HLS (on iOS) to see if they are working?

If you are still seeing issues - try one of our Quickstarts to confirm they are working for you.

- [.Net Quickstart for streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-dotnet-quickstart)
- [CLI Quickstart for streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-cli-quickstart)